# perl DBI MySQL Delete Statement with strange effect

Tags: mysql, perl, sql-delete, dbi

I have a very strange effect when trying to delete a row of a MySQL table.

The table relPartner has the following structure:

```
|-------------------------------------------|
| id | keyArtikel | keyPartner | Date       |
|.....................................------|
|  1 |      19670 |        116 | 2017-06-25 |
|  2 |      17942 |        116 | 2017-06-25 |
|  3 |      19416 |        116 | 2017-06-25 |
|  4 |      12286 |        116 | 2017-06-26 |
|  5 |      19848 |        127 | 2017-06-26 |
|  6 |      12968 |        127 | 2017-06-26 |
|  7 |      19859 |        127 | 2017-12-15 |
|  8 |      17942 |        119 | 2017-12-15 |
|  9 |      19678 |        119 | 2017-12-15 |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

The relevant perl code snippet:

```
my $relPartner = 9; # for testing try to delete row with id 9

my $data->{Result} = 'Success'; # Ajax Response

my $sql_query = 'DELETE FROM relPartner WHERE id = ?'

my $in = $dbh->do( $sql_query, undef, $relPartner );

if ((!defined ($in)) || (!$in)) {  
    $data->{Result} = 'Failed' 
} else {
    $data->{data}->{affectedRows} = $in;
    $data->{data}->{relPartner} = $relPartner;
}
```

I get the following result

```
{
    "data":
        {
            "affectedRows":"1",
            "relPartner":"9"
        },
    "Result":"Success"
}
```

And DBI logging the following result:

```
DEBUG - $do(0) = ['DELETE FROM relPartner WHERE id = ?
',undef,9];
DEBUG - affected(0): 1
DEBUG - disconnect(0)
```

So i thought the row #9 was deleted. But when i look at the table, the row #9 still exists.

I tested it on two different systems MySQL Server Version: 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 and 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 and get on both the same effect/result.

But on other tables the delete command with the same code work like expected.

So i hope anyone have an idea and can explain where my misunderstandig is.

Comment: I can't see a mistake in the code. Can you do a `SELECT` after the delete with the same arguments to see if you still get the row that should have been deleted?

Comment: That code will not run, you're missing a semicolon on the line containing the SQL statement (try to copy paste code, don't build it in the editor here, or you might leave out important stuff). Maybe try to build a minimal test case including the create table so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you certain that you're not doing this within a transaction that hasn't yet been committed? What is the value of `$dbh->{AutoCommit}`?

Comment: Are there any triggers defined?

Comment: @ Borodin, thanks there was my mistake!
$dbh->{AutoCommit} was 0, so a $dbh->commit() after the $dbh->do(...) was needed and now it works.

@jahn, you don't need a semicolon for a single sql-statment with Perl/DBI

Comment: @Arties you do need a semicolon on the end of the line that starts `my $sql_query = ...` (after the closing quote). The code you provided is obviously not _exactly_ the code you're running because it has a syntax error and wouldn't even run. Which meant that before someone could help you they first had to debug that unrelated problem.